# Accessing memory location using pseudo "file handle" in MATLAB

Tags: performance, matlab

There's lots of questions relating to dealing with large data sets by avoiding loading the whole thing into memory. My question is kind of the opposite: I've written code that reads files line by line to avoid memory overflow problems. However, I've just been given access to a powerful workstation with several hundred GB of memory, removing that problem, and making disk-access into the bottleneck.

Thing is, my code is written to access data files line by line using functions like `fgetl`. Is it possibly for me to somehow replace the file handle `f = fopen('datafile.txt')` with something else that acts in exactly the same way with respect to functions reading from a file, but instead of reading from the disk just returns values stored in memory?

I'm thinking, for example, having a large cell array with the contents of the file split by line and `fgetl` just returns the next. If I have to write my own wrapper for this, how can I go about doing this?

Comment: I think you might be stuck. However, next time look into `memmapfile` when you want to use a memory-mapped file...

Comment: That is possible, writing a class. Then `f = fopen_bufferedfile('datafile.txt')` would be the constructor and `fgetl(f)` would call the method `fgetl` which is equivalent to `f.fgetl()`. Is `fopen`, `fgetl` and `fclose` everything you need?

Comment: @Daniel Yep that's it: so can I just overload `fgetl` and `fclose` with my new class and replace the line where the file gets opened. Brill!

Comment: @rlbond Cheers for the pointer, I came across `memmapfile` after I'd already coded quite a bit with low level functions. Correct me if I'm wrong though, but wouldn't I still find myself in the position I'm in now if I had gone down the memmapfile route? Or does matlab load as much of the file into memory as it can comfortably handle so it scales nicely with increased resources?

Comment: @CharlieB: I think combining both approaches is the way to go, a class to match your existing code and `memmapfile` for a fast implementation.